# Mouse's special buttons are compatible with the hotkeys?

Tags: hotkeys, logitech-mouse

Is there a way to map eg. F5 (for a browser refresh) to a button on my mouse (logitech g600)?

Answer (score 0):

Install Logitech's SetPoint software from http://www.logitech.com/en-us/mice-pointers/articles/6077 .  Follow its instructions for your particular mouse.  You might even be able to map F5 only in your web browser, but still use the button for other things when not in the web browser.